# Get wold coordinates from screen coordinates in Babylon.js

Tags: babylonjs

I'm not using a ground. I want to get the pickedPoint to add a mesh dynamically.

```
scene.onPointerDown = function (evt, pickResult) {
     // if the click hits the ground object, we change the impact position
     if (pickResult.hit) {
         console.log('an object is picked');
     } else {
         console.log('get world coordinates from evt.x and evt.y');
     }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

the pickResult object has a variable called `pickedPoint` .

Here is a quick demo:

https://playground.babylonjs.com/#NU4F6Y#0

Comment: Thanks for your response. I went to have the pickedPoint without using a ground or a plane. But I think that the plane is necessary.

Comment: it is impossible to get a point in space without having some point of reference, When you click a 3D scene on a 2D screen - how deep is the click? 100 units? 2? Or, do you want to screen coordinates instead?

Comment: I finally used the screen coordinates and got from it the world coordinates and it's ok..

Comment: Make sure to use false for the `fastPick` argument, or you'll get inaccurate results when picking non-horizontal surfaces.